# How do I get angularFire objects to orderBy with ngRepeat?

Tags: angularjs, angularfire

The current bunch of data in my firebase looks something like:

`{"-JZ7b":{"name":"bob","has":"slack"},"-JZ7a":{"name":"connie","has":"slack"}}`

If I use something like:

```
<ul><li ng-repeat="(key, person) in people |orderBy 'name'"></li></ul>
```

I get:

- -JZ7a connie has slack
- -JZ7b bob has slack

[here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vVk6E/17/)

What is the best way to get the expected orderBy [without changing my data into some other format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14330878/angular-js-orderby-not-working-with-dict-syntax-on-ng-repeat)? I realize that in this example the keys aren't exactly meaningful but, assume they are. The idea of a building a custom directive seems like an interesting option but, my code can be a bit jangly compared to the original.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OrderBy doesn't apply to objects. You can use the filter [toArray](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1286).

```
<li ng-repeat="p in people | toArray | orderBy: 'name'" ng-click="cpSelect(p.$key)">
    {{p.$key}} {{p.name}} has {{p.has}}
</li>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/62exD/

Comment: The toArray filter works perfect. Maybe edit `ng-click="cpSelect(pid)"` to `ng-click="cpSelect(p.$key)"` for posterity.

Comment: Worth nothing that there's no such filter in 1.2.x, but the `orderByPriority` one provided by angularFire does the job.

Comment: @finishingmove Not sure what are you talking about...did I say the filter is in angular? Just copy the code from that ticket and use it.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `orderByPriority` to convert `firebase` objects into array and then apply normal filter and orderBy.

```
 <ul>
   <li ng-repeat="person in people | orderByPriority | orderBy: 'name'">
     <span>{{ person.$id }} </span>
   </li>
 </ul>
```

Refer `orderbypriority`
https://www.firebase.com/docs/angular/reference.html#orderbypriority

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are trying to filter over an object which will not work.

[Filtering on object map rather than array in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13887504/filtering-on-object-map-rather-than-array-in-angularjs)

If you have control over the format of your data, best practice with angular is :

```
var objs = [
{ name : 'Whatever' , has : 'value' , etc : 'etc' },
{ name : 'Whatever' , has : 'value' , etc : 'etc' },
{ name : 'Whatever' , has : 'value' , etc : 'etc' }
]
<div ng-repeat="obj in objs | orderBy : name">...
```