# Firebase AngularJS ng-repeat orderby.. how?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm a bit lost at this point, looked for answers online but I'm still doing something wrong..
SCENARIO: 
I've a firebase obj from where I get items to be repeated through ng-repeat, the loop works perfectly, however I cannot figure out how to order this elements by a value of the children, basically this is how it is now:

app.js

```
    .controller('MessageController', function ($scope, $firebase) {

        var ref = new Firebase("https://01062016ag.firebaseio.com/messages/yourmessages/02");
        var fb = $firebase(ref);

        // sync as object
        var syncObject = fb.$asObject();
        var time = Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP ? Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP : 1459007018632;

        this.newMessage = { approved:false, time:Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP };
        this.addMessage = function($event) {
            $event.preventDefault();
            ref.push(this.newMessage);
            this.newMessage = {};
        };
        console.log(syncObject, ref, fb);

        // three way data binding
        syncObject.$bindTo( $scope, 'messages' );
    })
```

html

```
 <carousel interval="myInterval">

                            <div id="preview">

                                <blockquote ng-class="{ 'preview' : !msgCtrl.newMessage.text }" class="active">
                                    {{ msgCtrl.newMessage.text ? msgCtrl.newMessage.text : 'leave a message' }}
                                </blockquote>
                                <cite ng-class="{ 'preview' : !msgCtrl.newMessage.author }" class="">
                                    {{ msgCtrl.newMessage.author ? msgCtrl.newMessage.author : 'Author' }}
                                </cite>

                            </div>

                            <slide ng-repeat="slide in messages | orderBy: 'time' : reverse " active="slide.active">
                                <blockquote>
                                    {{ slide.text | limitTo: 100 }}{{slide.text.length > 100 ? ' ...' : ''}}
                                </blockquote>
                                <cite>
                                    {{ slide.author }}
                                </cite>
                            </slide>
                        </carousel>
```

I tried applying filters to the ng-repeat as explained in some thread, something like `ng-repeat="slide in messages | orderByPriority | orderBy: 'time' : reverse " or ng-repeat="slide in messages | toArray | orderBy: 'time' : reverse "`

But no luck.. I get errors for Unknown provider injector
I'm pretty sure there's something wrong with my controller anyway..

Sorry if it looks a bit nooby but I'm pretty new with angular :)

Thanks for all your help

Comment: What version of Firebase and AngularFire are you using?

Comment: One way is to [order in AngularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19844359/how-do-i-get-angularfire-objects-to-orderby-with-ngrepeat), the other way is to [sort with Firebase Qeuries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29164753/retrieve-record-with-query-angularfire). The latter is preferred, since it performs the sorting and filtering on the server.

Comment: Frank van Puffelen yep the second's preferred, and orderByPriority  is what should do the job.. But I didn't understand how to to set the filter up in the controller and I get unknown.. Any advice or suggest appreciated

Comment: Your code doesn't use a query yet and doing so won't result in needing a filter in the controller. Sinan's answer to the second question I linked shows how to make it work. Start with his example (or one of the many, many examples of using `orderByChild()` out there and in the [Firebase documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-queries)) and work from there. Don't start from a broken app and try to make it work, start from the docs and understand it first.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion Frank :) that's what I'm trying to do, but still I miss some step,
just starting from scratch and following the docs I get orderByChild() as an undefined function with this sentence

var ref = new Firebase("https://dinosaur-facts.firebaseio.com/dinosaurs");
ref.orderByChild("height").on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.key() + " was " + snapshot.val().height + " meters tall");
});

which should work pretty much out of the box, or do I have to define this function somehow (that's the very beginning of the query section..)

Comment: I had an outdated version of firebase and angular fire..
[facepalm]