# Angular template: Loop over object, sort by values

Tags: angularjs

I have a javascript object that I want to loop over in angular. The keys in the object are names and the value is a rank. I want to sort the elements by the rank. I tried this which didn't work:

```
ng-repeat="(name, rank) in topCategories | orderBy: '-rank'"
```

I also tried without the single quotes around the word "rank".
The result is that the elements are looped over but not sorted. No error is logged. Is it possible to sort when iterating over objects?

Example data source:

```
{
    foo: 5,
    bar: 7,
    baz: 42
}
```

**Edit** After inspecting the source code it is easy to see that the `orderBy` filter simply just returns at once if the supplied argument is an object and not an array. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/filter/orderBy.js#L68

Comment: Can you post example js object? The one you loop trough... it's not very clear.

Comment: "rand" here is user-defined string, not related to object fields. Your "name" variable will always contain a key and "rank" - value of iterated object (not value of "object.rank" field).

Comment: `(name, rank) in topCategories`

If topCategories is an array (I think so because of plural), then you are doing it wrong.

Comment: @Iansen Example added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having your data structured as just an object has always made it difficult for me to repeat over. I've always needed to convert it to an array of objects first. Rather than having your data as:

```
{
    foo: 5,
    bar: 7,
    baz: 42
}
```

Try doing it as an array of objects:

```
[
  {name: 'foo', rank: 5}
  {name: 'bar', rank: 7}
  {name: 'baz', rank: 42}
]
```

Then your html is simple:

```
ng-repeat="result in topCategories | orderBy: '-rank'"
```

**[Plunker Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/M7H39qRBIzozP1Ypyx9Z?p=preview)**

sources:

[Google Groups: Order by object?](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/RBWLTHzmtBw)

[Orderby not working with dict syntax on ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14330878/orderby-not-working-with-dict-syntax-on-ng-repeat)

[Has been previously addressed as an issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1286).

The sources say that `orderBy` requires an array of objects