# How do I order ng-repeat items?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My options object for the select looks like this:

```
{
    3 : 'c',
    5 : 'a',
    6 : 'b',
    ...
}
```

my repeat looks like this:

```
<option ng-repeat="(k,v) in field.options" value="{{k}}">{{v}}</option>
```

I want to order by the values (v), but as far as I can tell, `orderBy` only works with a key of the object, which does not work for this format.

Comment: orderBy also takes function that will allow you to set custom sort https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy

Comment: In that case I should be able to say `orderBy: String(v)` after adding String to the scope, but that didn't work.

Comment: Off topic, but if you didn't need the overhead of a scope per option, you could use `ngOptions` instead.

Comment: @adam0101 Angular doesn't always render the options when I use `ngOptions` since I fetch the value of the select and the options asynchronously. Hard to explain but this was the best (only) choice.

Comment: That's odd. I've used `ngOptions` asynchronously before with no issues.

Comment: @KthProg if that's happening then you might need to call `$scope.$apply();` after your `options` property gets updated to let angular know that it's been updated

Comment: possible duplicate of **[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14330878/orderby-not-working-with-dict-syntax-on-ng-repeat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14330878/orderby-not-working-with-dict-syntax-on-ng-repeat)**

Comment: @adam0101 I'm using the beta that might have something to do with it.

Comment: @mikelt21 Yeah, but why do that when I could just use `ng-repeat`? I'd rather let Angular handle the digest cycles.

Comment: @mikelt21 It does appear to be a duplicate. Apparently this is just not possible but the feature has been requested. What a PITA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written in the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy), `orderBy` only works with arrays. Therefore, it might be suitable for you to convert your object into an array and simply call `sort()`.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/10591/)

Comment: I did in fact do that and it did the trick. The problem was rewriting all of the code which simply accessed the values by their keys, since I now had to traverse the list to do the equivalent.

It's still pretty fast but maybe I'll sort and do a binary search on the array? The array looks like this [{k:'key',v:'value'},... etc].