# Angularjs foreach only returns one object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs

This could be something simple and I'm overlooking it. But I'm building out a filter by categories and once a user clicks a category it updates a scope (my instance $scope.productStuff) and display the objects accordingly. My problem is when I click the category it gives me back the mulitple objects in my console. Then I look at the dom and it only shows one object (and it's the last object) instead all the objects that are in my console.
Here is my function:

```
$scope.update = function(val) {
  angular.forEach($scope.productStuff, function(item){
    if( item.s2 === val.toUpperCase()){
      $scope.productStuff = [item];
    }       
  });
}
```

Here is my factory that's getting the data on page load

```
dataFactory.getProducts().then(function(res){
  $scope.productStuff = res.data;
  $scope.loading = false;
});
```

So my question is why is it displaying one object in the dom and multiple objects in the console and how do I put the items on the $scope.productStuff?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$scope.update = function(val) {
  // Create an empty array
  var stuff = [];
  angular.forEach($scope.productStuff, function(item){
    if( item.s2 === val.toUpperCase() ){
      // push to our array when condition is met (filter)
      stuff.push(item);
    }       
  });
  // $scope.productStuff now contains all the filtered items
  $scope.productStuff = stuff;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I've been stuck on this for a hour now! Such an easy solution.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to modify iterate over and modifying $scope.productStuff too. As soon as you write:

```
 $scope.productStuff = [item];
```

only one item remains in it. try creating a new array and once done assign it to $scope.productStuff

```
$scope.update = function(val) {
  var tempArray = [];
  angular.forEach($scope.productStuff, function(item){
    if( item.s2 === val.toUpperCase()){
      tempArray.push(item);
    }       
  });
  $scope.productStuff = tempArray;
}
```